# How to check expiry of token via expiry_time coming with that in javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, flipkart-api

I am getting an access token from Flipkart API and gives me token with its expiry time . But i don't know what they given in expiry time they are giving some kind of timestamp in seconds,  as i convert those seconds into minutes then there are 56 days like something that is coming. As i read the doc for that they said that token is expired after 60 days. But as i hit the API it will giving me different different time-stamp  in expiry_time field each time. 
For example first timme it will give:-

```
"access_token" : "0c87d3c8-824d-446b-bqf8-c14e7d49f06",
"expires_in" : 4773358
```

After some time i hit it again then it returns:-

```
"access_token" : "0c87d3c8-824d-446b-bqf8-c14e7d49f06",
"expires_in" : 4840646
```

I just want to validate this token via its expiry time i.e. if token is expire i need to hit again and get fresh token.How can i check that token is expired or not.

How can i achieve this using java script or Meteor framework. Or i also want to know on which format they gives me this time-stamp in seconds i think or in some other.As they said that token is expired in 60 days but as i convert this it shows only 56 days not 60 so please explain this for me as well if somebody know.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect they are giving you a token that expires at midnight on a particular day of the week rather than 60*24*3600 = 5,184,000 seconds from now. To convert this expiry delay to a specific datetime, do the following:

```
const expiryDate = Date.now() + expires_in * 1000
```

You have to multiply by 1000 because `Date.now()` returns milliseconds.

Comment: can also use Date.now() and have it in one line: `(expiryDate = Date.now() + expires_in * 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
export const expiryToISODate = (expiresIn: number): string => {
  const now = new Date();
  now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + expiresIn);
  return now.toISOString();
};
```